# returning a nsdictionary from a method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface GenerarPassword: NSObject
{
    int password; 
}
@property int password;

-(NSString*) GenerarValor:(NSString*) key;
-(NSDictionary*) getDiccionario;
-(int) password;
//-(NSArray*)generarlistaletras:(int)numero;
-(int) generarClave;
-(void) printPassword;
-(void)setPassword:(int)nuevoValor;
/*
-(int) generarNumeroAleatorio;
 -(NSArray *) generarListadeUsuarios;
*/
 @end

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "GenerarPassword.h"

    @implementation GenerarPassword
    -(NSDictionary*) getDiccionario
    {
    NSDictionary* m_Dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          @"1", @"Dx",
          @"2", @"Om",
          @"3", @"Al",
          @"4", @"Dx",
          @"5", @"Je",
          @"6", @"Ko",
          @"7", @"Ke",
          @"8", @"Fi",
          @"9", @"Re",
          @"10", @"Me",
          @"11", @"Mu",
          @"12", @"Ra",
          @"13", @"Lu",
          @"14", @"Lo",
          @"15", @"Ka"];

        return m_Dict;
    }
    -(int) password
    {
          return password;
    }
    -(void) setPassword:(int)nuevoValor 
    {
          password = nuevoValor;
    }

    -(void) printPassword
    {
          NSLog(@"%d",password);
    }
    /*Se genera la clave numérica*/
    -(int) generarClave
    {
          srand(time(0));
        int r = rand() %(9999-1000+1) +1000;
        return r;
    }

    //- (NSArray*) generarlistaletras:(int)numero
    //{
    //      return nil;
    //}
    //Esta función Genera el valor Aleatorio
    -(NSString*) GenerarValor:(NSString*) key
    {

          NSString *valor = [[self generarDiccionario] valueForKey: key];
          return valor;
    }

         // return (generarDiccionario().get(key))
         // lista = [0,0,0]
          //lista[random.randrange(0,3)] = [GenerarValor(numero)]

          //for i in range(len(lista)):
         //       if lista[i] == 0:
         //             lista[i] = [GenerarValor(random.randrange(11,20))]
         // return lista
    @end

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
          NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        GenerarPassword *Generar1 = [[GenerarPassword alloc]init];
          int clave = [Generar1 generarClave];
          [Generar1 setPassword: clave];
          NSDictionary* dict = [Generar1 getDiccionario];
          NSLog(@"%a",[Generar1 GenerarValor: @"3"]);
          [pool drain];
        return 0;
    }
```

I am really desperate, i just want to use the dictionary but at the compiling time i get a few warnings and when i run the program i get the following error: ": Uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: Can not determine type information for -[GenerarPassword (null)]
"

Comment: What are the warnings?

Comment: It can create confusion (and probably a complier warning) to create an instance variable and a property of the same name (password). Delete the ivar, and the password and setPassword methods; you get both of those for free with a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see missing nil at the end of the object/key list:

```
NSDictionary* m_Dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      @"1", @"Dx",
      @"2", @"Om",
      @"3", @"Al",
      @"4", @"Dx",
      @"5", @"Je",
      @"6", @"Ko",
      @"7", @"Ke",
      @"8", @"Fi",
      @"9", @"Re",
      @"10", @"Me",
      @"11", @"Mu",
      @"12", @"Ra",
      @"13", @"Lu",
      @"14", @"Lo",
      @"15", @"Ka",
      nil];

    return m_Dict;
}
```

and generarDiccionario method not declared (I don't see any method matching this name). Did you mean getDiccionario?

```
-(NSString*) GenerarValor:(NSString*) key
{

    NSString *valor = [[self getDiccionario] valueForKey: key];
    return valor;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the help , yes i missed that!

Answer (score 0):

On my environment, NSInvalidArgumentException didn't appeared. But there are some mistakes to fix.

On the method 'dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys', you must first write the object , then the key, nil for last.

```
NSDictionary *m_Dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"Dx", @"1",
        @"Om", @"2",
        @"Al", @"3",
        @"Dx", @"4",
        @"Je", @"5",
        @"Ko", @"6",
        @"Ke", @"7",
        @"Fi", @"8",
        @"Re", @"9",
        @"Me", @"10",
        @"Mu", @"11",
        @"Ra", @"12",
        @"Lu", @"13",
        @"Lo", @"14",
        @"Ka", @"15", 
        nil];
```

There is no method 'generarDiccionario'. Do you mean 'getDiccionario'?

```
- (NSString *)GenerarValor:(NSString *)key
{
    //NSString *valor = [[self generarDiccionario] valueForKey: key]; <-Not found
    NSString *valor = [[self getDiccionario] valueForKey: key]; //Do you mean this?
    return valor;
}
```

The format identifier is '%@' for NSString*.

```
NSLog(@"%a",[Generar1 GenerarValor: @"3"]); //Error

NSLog(@"%@",[Generar1 GenerarValor: @"3"]);
```

Perhaps it will work after fix them.

Comment: Thx for the help buddy, I am new in objective c :(